# How do I suppress Rails "Expire fragment" log messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I'm working on a Rails site that I did not create, and some of my log messages are hard to find in the sea of "Expire fragment" messages in `log/production.log`.  It does not seem to indicate any sort of problem, so I'd like to suppress those messages and make it easy to find the messages my code is generating.  Is there any way to suppress them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the logger in an initializer, like [here](http://heliom.ca/blog/posts/disable-rails-cache-logging).

```
# Create logger that ignores messages containing “CACHE”
class CacheFreeLogger < ::Logger
  def debug(message, *args, &block)
    super unless message.include? 'Expire fragment'
  end
end

# Overwrite ActiveRecord’s logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
  CacheFreeLogger.new(STDOUT)) unless Rails.env.test?
```

Comment: That might be the right idea, but ActiveRecord::Base.logger is not the logger I need to override.  Apparently neither is config.logger.

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f2bff250a017b6da76b7587a164643db31ffbf9b/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/fragments.rb#L79) you may want to override [ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html)

Comment: It doesn't look like I can override that with a customized Logger class.  What would that override look like? If something's subscribed to those notifications and responds to them by issuing log messages, I would think a customized logger could still suppress the messages.